# Import and export data to excel for asp.net mvc using entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, excel, entity-framework

I want to import and export excel file data into SQL server using 
 **ASP.NET MVC** using entity framework.

All code that I found explain that without using entity framework.  So what should I do to make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) is a .NET library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx). Here is sample code to use this libarary in ASP.net MVC.

```
public FileContentResult Download()
{

    var fileDownloadName = String.Format("FileName.xlsx");
    const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";


    // Pass your ef data to method
    ExcelPackage package = GenerateExcelFile(_db.Contexts.ToList());

    var fsr = new FileContentResult(package.GetAsByteArray(), contentType);
    fsr.FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;

    return fsr;
}

private static ExcelPackage GenerateExcelFile(IEnumerable<Context> datasource)
{

    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();

    //Create the worksheet 
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");

    // Sets Headers
    ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Column 1";
    ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Column 2";
    ws.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Column 3";

    // Inserts Data
    for (int i = 0; i < datasource.Count(); i++)
    {
        ws.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Serial;
        ws.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).WarrantyStart;
        ws.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).WarrantyEnd;
    }

    // Format Header of Table
    using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:C1"])
    {

        rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid; //Set Pattern for the background to Solid 
        rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Gold); //Set color to DarkGray 
        rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Black);
    }
    return pck;
}
```

And insert this link in your view and it will download your file.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download Data as Excel", "Download");
```

Similarly you can import data from excel, [here](http://www.thewebflash.com/2014/12/importexport-data-from-excel-files-xlsx.html) is an example to get started.

Comment: here I'm trying to populate data table like this `ExcelPackage package = GenerateExcelFile(db.Product.ToList());` but I'm getting following error `cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<project.Models.Product>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Context>'`

Comment: @kez, Refactor `IEnumerable<Context> datasource` to `IEnumerable<project.Models.Product> datasource`

Comment: I just changed as you said `private static ExcelPackage GenerateExcelFile(IEnumerable<project.Models.Product> datasource)
        {` but then error changed as `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<project.Models.AB_Product>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<project.Models.Product>'`

Comment: Here `Context` means the type of your collection. so i supposed looking at the exception is `project.Models.Product`, Replace it it `project.Models.AB_Product`, it should solve the problem

Comment: Can I give custom  title for this kind excel sheet , if so whats the syntax ?